# When using EntityType to show a select, can't save entity from Symfony form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two related entities in my symfony project - which are stored using Doctrine.  One entity is "Advertiser" which has an id and a name.  The other entity - which is causing the problem - is for a "Report" which has an id of it's own along with a field called "advertiser_id".

When adding a report for an advertiser, in the Symfony form, I'm using EntityType for the advertiser_id field so that I can display a select of advertisers.  That part is working great, but when I try to submit the form, I get an error because it's passing an Advertiser object instead of the id of the advertiser to the advertiser_id field.

Here's what I have in my form's builder:

```
$builder
    ->add('advertiser_id', EntityType::class, [
        'class'        => Advertiser::class,
        'query_builder' => $this->advertiserRepository->findAllNotDeletedUnpaginated(),
        'choice_label' => 'name',

    ])
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Submit',
    ])
;
```

When I submit the form, I get this error:
Expected argument of type "integer", "App\Entity\Advertiser" given.

Any idea on how I can force symfony to only try to save the id of the advertiser that was selected rather than passing the entire advertiser?

> > UPDATE: Now that I've refactored it so that the advertiser is a related entity to report, I'm trying to figure out how to make the advertiser a hidden field and getting nowhere.

I've tried the code the iiirxs mentioned previously with the callback transformer - changing 'advertiser_id' to 'advertiser' - but I've had no luck with that.  I've been reading posts like this [Symfony hiddenType using data_class for entity instead of transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640543/symfony-hiddentype-using-data-class-for-entity-instead-of-transformer), but I'm having trouble getting the value for 'advertiser' the way they are getting $options['selected_course'] in that example.

When I try (for testing purposes) hard coding a value of 1 for advertiser, then putting this on the form, the form shows, but I get an error when submitting it:

```
    $advertiser=1;

    $builder
        ->add('advertiser', HiddenType::class,['data' => $advertiser, 'data_class' => null])
```

The error I get when submitting the form is:
Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Advertiser or null", "string" given.

I'm sorry for beating a dead horse about this.  This seems like it should be such a common/easy thing to do, but I'm having a hard time finding how to make it a hidden field.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please check `advertiser_id` this field definition in your Entity. If it defined as integer, you should change it.

Comment: can you share your `Report.php` entity file here? Did you indicate the field type as ManyToOne in the annotations?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to pass an ID and not the Entity to your form ? (symfony is actually doing the job for you to serialize / deserialize EntityType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not defined correctly an association with Advertiser entity in your Report entity. You should have defined an association like this:

```
// inside Report.php class

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Advertiser")
 */
private $advertiser;
```

instead of defining a field that holds the foreign key `advertiser_id`. Doctrine is smart enough to map the advertiser field to an `advertiser_id` foreign key on your database on its own, so it would be better to use an association mapping. You can find more in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship).

However, if you indeed have to use only an integer to store the `advertiser_id` as an integer for your own reasons, you should use Symfony's Data Transformer to transform the advertiser entity to an integer like this:

```
$advertiserRepository = $this->advertiserRepository;
$builder->get('advertiser_id')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($advertiserAsInteger) use ($advertiserRepository) {
                // transform the integer to an entity object
                return $advertiserRepository->find($advertiserAsInteger);
            },
            function ($advertiserAsEntity) {
                // transform the entity back to an integer
                return $advertiserAsEntity->getId();
            }
        ))
    ;
```

In my code above I used a CallbackTransformer to implement the transformation but you could also use a transformer class to do it. You can find also more about this in the [data transformers documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

Comment: Thank you, iiirxs!  I'm going to refactor my entity per your first suggestion.

Comment: I've refactored the app so that the Advertiser is related to the Report.  Now I'm trying to render the form for a report and I'm trying to figure out how to display the advertiser in the form.  I've tried the basic "->add('advertiser')" within the builder, but that gives me this error: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Advertiser could not be converted to string.  Any thoughts - or links - on how to render the form properly when there is a related entity would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you added advertiser field in your form as EntityType?

Comment: Thanks again, iiirxs!  Changing the builder to include this worked!              ->add('advertiser', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Advertiser::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to part of the answer by @iiirxs with a custom type I just implemented based on the model transformer suggestion.

This type extends the built-in `EntityType` so for a lot of cases, you could replace `EntityType` with `EntityReferenceType` and map the id instead.

This is useful for if the form does not map directly to the entity, for example using the command pattern, so you'd prefer an identifier.

```php
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class EntityReferenceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'id_property' => 'id'
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(
            new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($entityIdentifier) use ($options) {
                    if ($entityIdentifier === null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return $options['em']->getRepository($options['class'])->find($entityIdentifier);
                },
                function ($entity) use ($options) {
                    if ($entity === null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor()->getValue($entity, $options['id_property']);
                }
            )
        );
    }


    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```