# Symfony entities are not updated in database after changes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My symfony app is using Doctrine to persist entities in mysql.

Today I updated my entities "Advertiser" and "Report" so there are relations between the two - as suggested in this post: [When using EntityType to show a select, can't save entity from Symfony form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638517/when-using-entitytype-to-show-a-select-cant-save-entity-from-symfony-form)

When I try creating a migration, it says that the database is already in sync.

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

Returns:
[WARNING] No database changes were detected.
The database schema and the application mapping information are already in sync.

However if I look at the table for the report, I see it still has the old schema:

```
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| advertiser_id | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date    | date       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date      | date       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted       | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Even though my entity looks like this now:

```
class Report
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $start_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $end_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Advertiser", inversedBy="reports")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $advertiser;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->start_date;
    }

    public function setStartDate(\DateTimeInterface $start_date): self
    {
        $this->start_date = $start_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->end_date;
    }

    public function setEndDate(\DateTimeInterface $end_date): self
    {
        $this->end_date = $end_date;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDeleted(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    public function setDeleted(bool $deleted): self
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdvertiser(): ?Advertiser
    {
        return $this->advertiser;
    }

    public function setAdvertiser(?Advertiser $advertiser): self
    {
        $this->advertiser = $advertiser;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I've been searching for solutions and have tried these, but no luck:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how I can update my database with my updated schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem was that I previously had a property called "advertiser_id" (int) on the report object.  And possibly I was trying to change too many things at once for doctrine to manage.  Previously, I had tried to remove the advertiser_id while adding the relation property for advertiser.

To get doctrine working again, I removed the advertiser property from the Report object - along with the getters and setters.  I also removed the reverse lookup stuff from the Advertiser object.  When I tried to run the migration, it seems like there were several migrations that it was trying to run - all doing the same thing: dropping a foreign key that doesn't exist.  So I commented out all of those commands in the migration files and finally was able to get it to migrate.  I also removed the advertiser_id property.  The app is working again.

Then I tried adding the "advertiser" relation property back to the report.  This time it worked as expected and I was able to migrate.  So I think the issue is related to my object already having an advertiser_id property.  Now that I've added the advertiser relation to the Report object, I see that doctrine added an advertiser_id column to the table.  I suspect that it being present previously was the reason things broke down.

Thanks for the replies!  Glad to have it working again.

Comment: In case it can help others, for me it was just a matter of a wrong namespace set in my entity class. I had duplicated an entity from another package and forgot to update the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, try clearing the cache with:

```
symfony console cache:clear
```

Comment: The answer that helped me.
I had already deleted the databaseand Symfony didn't recognize the changes, clearing the cache fell like a glove, thanks!

I run: ´´php bin/console cache:clear 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata´´

Answer (score 1):

As a **many to one** relation, it's normal that you're database advertiser column only stores the key of the report as a "link" to it, so that's why Symfony doesn't see any changes in your DB.

Maybe you can also use :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

to see changes in your DB

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

to apply changes without using migrations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's useful for someone, but **when using annotations make sure that the comment block follows the DocBlock format**, the first line should have two asterisks: `/**` and not a single asterisk `/*`

DocBlock

```
/**
*
*/
```

PHP Multiline comment

```
/*
*
*
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper annotation setup may be missing required configuration, you can always try to validate your schema with `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Advertiser", inversedBy="reports")
 * @JoinColumn(name="advertiser_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $advertiser;
```

And check Advertiser entity for issues as well, maybe it is missing primary key or something.

Comment: Running the command you specified, produces this:                                                                                                                      
 [OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                    
 [OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: I'm confused what the JoinColumn values would be.  I used the Symfony console to alter the Report entity - adding the advertiser as a relation type and setting up the reverse on the Advertiser entity so it can get the Reports.  The field of advertiser_id that appears in my SQL results is the old property that no longer exists in my entity code (but hasn't been removed from mysql).  The new property that the console added to my report is called "advertiser" - it's the whole object.  So I don't believe including advertiser_id in my JoinColumn annotation is what is needed.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand what is the problem then. But you have to alter and advertiser table as well, but you have not posted it here, so I cannot judge what is wrong without advertiser entity code.

Comment: What you have now is unidirectional association, what you need is bidirectional association. If you retrieve report you will see advertiser attached to it, but you cant see reports when you retrieve advertiser. Please provide us with your advertiser code.

Comment: The problem wasn't with the annotations or code.  Something went wrong with the migrations - I believe because I already had a field called "advertiser_id", which I was removing at the same time I was adding the advertiser object as a property.  When I did it a step at a time - removing the advertiser_id property first, migrating, then using bin/console make:entity to add the related advertiser object, it worked as expected.

Comment: Yes Doctrine got confused. I recommend you to have control over column names, dont leave blank annotations, because most bundles and libraries will use snake_case for their column names and your will be automatically generated CamelCase, just for cleaner code control column and table names.